# Deleting all Contacts programmatically

Tags: android, contacts

The delete all contacts method that seems to do it's job is:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = myActivity.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,  null, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
       Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
       contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

Is there a way to adjust this to delete RawContacts instead of contacts? Something like this:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = myActivity.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        contentResolver.delete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
        }
```

I'm looking for other ways to delete all contacts. What's the best way to clear all the contact tables (Contacts, Raw Contacts, Data)?

Comment: Is this for a prank or something? I question the usefulness of deleting all contacts. Still, upvoting for curiosity.

Comment: Seems like it. But no, the app blows away all the contacts and syncs new ones. It seems ill-advised but the phone will only be used for that app, not your personal contacts.